# What do add_filters() and apply_filter() do?

Tags: filters

I'm a bit confused as to why this isn't working - although it must be said I'm not that sure what `apply_filters()` and `add_filter` are doing, so any general tips would be great too!

I want a query that brings up the five earlier posts on a single post page. I am sending the current post's date off, and want to apply a filter that filters out posts earlier than this.

```
function sw_filter_posts_before( $where = '', $date) {

    $where .= " AND post_date < '" . $date . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

How do I correctly apply this? Simply using add_filter or apply_filter before instantiating a new WP_Query object doesn't seem to work correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: To go into things further, I would like to understand how to pass a variable into the filter, as I can't get $date to pass from another function.

Here is said other function (it is an ajax call within wordpress, hence I start by getting the post ID for the current page through a $_POST variable):

```
function create_more_videos_sidebar() {

    $id = $_POST['theID'];

    $args = array(  'post_type'         =>  'videos',
                    'posts_per_page'    =>  1,
                    'p'             =>  $id
                ); 

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

        $date = get_the_date('Y-m-d');

    endwhile;

    $args = array(  'post_type'         =>  'videos',
                    'posts_per_page'    =>  5
                ); 

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'sw_filter_videos_before' ); //don't know how to pass $date


    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'sw_filter_videos_before' );

    //do loop stuff

    $response = json_encode( array( 'result' => $result ) );

    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Okay, first things, first: to what hook, exactly, are you trying to add your filter? That matters, because your `$date` variable uses `$post` data, so we need to know if we're filtering *inside* or *outside* of the Loop.

Comment: I think this might be where my lack of wp filters knowledge is striking me down. I thought the hook was 'posts_where', and it would add the given string to the SQL query. As far as I'm aware that's outside of the loop, as it's in the preprocessing part of creating a loop. Do you have a suggestion on how I would achieve my goal with best practice?

Comment: Sure, we can get there. :) What date do you want to use? Asked more accurately: how do you want to *determine* what date to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you attempting to filter? I'll assume you're trying to add a filter to a filter hook called `posts_before`. In which case, you need to *add* your filter to this hook, via `add_filter()`:

```
function mytheme_filter_posts_before( $where = '', $date) {

    $where .= " AND post_date < '" . $date . "'";
    return $where;
}
// Add function to the filter hook
add_filter( 'posts_before', 'mytheme_filter_posts_before' );
```

Note that I changed your function name. `filter_posts_before()` is far too generic of a function name, and very likely to cause a function-naming collision.

### EDIT

And just to clarify:

- `apply_filters()` is the **filter hook location**, is called by **core code**, and is used to **apply** any filters that are **added to the queue** by Themes/Plugins (and core).
- `add_filter()` is called by **Themes/Plugins** (and core), and is used to **add filters to the queue** to be applied to the hook by core.

### EDIT 2

Based on your comment above, the hook is `posts_where`. So, let's take a crack at re-building your callback function:

```
function mytheme_filter_posts_where( $where ) {

    // Here, we need to figure out how to
    // determine what date to use. In your 
    // code example, you call get_the_date(),
    // but this function must be used inside
    // the Loop. Let's try get_the_time()
    // instead. You'll just need to come up
    // with a way to determine what post ID to use.
    $post = 'some_post_id';
    $date = get_the_time( 'Y-m-d', $post );

    $where .= " AND post_date < '" . $date . "'";
    return $where;
}
// Add function to the filter hook
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'mytheme_filter_posts_where' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll make sure to rename the filter. I still don't understand how to pass the $date variable to this, could you clarify that, too? Thanks!

Comment: What is the `$date` variable, and where is it coming from?

Comment: $date is coming from another function of mine, it is the date of the current post, in the format 'Y-m-d'.

Comment: Are you globalizing `$date`, or returning it from the function, what? Can you post that function's code, also?

Comment: Okey-cokey, I've updated the original post with some more details. I could globalize date, but is that entirely necessary? Is it not best, if possible, to just pass it over somehow?

Comment: I've updated my answer. We just need to come up with a way to determine the post ID to reference in order to get the correct date to use in the query.

Comment: Absolutely. I took your initial advice and have the post ID coming in from the page via json, and then I just globalize it. Which works fine, but I assume it's not best practice? Everything works lovely now, but I'd feel a lot better if I could pass this data privately instead. Thanks so much for your help so far.